# Resolving a dependency mess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, rack

Trying to squeeze in a fairly new gem, and its causing me to stumble around updating quite a few others including Rails as a whole from 2.3.5 to 2.3.6.

Bundler installs fine.

But when I boot up `script/console`, I get this :

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.3)
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:271:in `require_frameworks':RuntimeError: can't activate rack (~> 1.0.0, runtime), already activated rack-1.1.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:117:in `gem': can't activate rack (~> 1.0.0, runtime), already activated rack-1.1.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller.rb:34
```

1. It's strange that it says `Rails 2.3.3` .. not sure why..
2. I can't figure out where/how it's loading or trying to load Rack 1.0.0 now that I've updated it to Rack 1.1.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Bundler and running into dependency issues using a local binary, try prefixing that script with `bundle exec`:

```
bundle exec script/console
```

Under the hood, this does the following:

1. Starts a new ruby process that calls Bundler.setup (thereby loading all your bundler deps)
2. Executes the command you passed `bundler exec` in the context of your Bundler dependencies

This tends to solve most problems. If you're still having issues after that, your best bet is to verify your shell's environment variables are correct and debug from there.

**PS**: If your issue is what I think it is, the problem here is that `script/console` is pulling your system gems instead of the ones provided by bundler, which is why you're seeing the incorrect version of Rack and getting load errors for your other gems.

Comment: Also important to note is that you should use the proper [Rails 2.3 installation procedure for bundler](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html). There are other ways that mostly work, but have problems like this, so it's worth checking.

Comment: Yah it doesn't seem that changing the rails version to 2.3.6 from 2.3.3 actually upgraded the Rails app. Maybe its because my app is somehow vendoring some old data?